# How should I use Dagger2 with Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-2

I'm working in a project and I need to inject Retrofit object with Dagger 2. I search info but I only have been able to do a few steps and now I don't know how to continue:

My component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(NetworkModule::class))
interface NetworkComponent {
    fun inject(foo: TheApplication)
}
```

My module:

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.chucknorris.io/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

}
```

And now I see I have to make a `Class` who extends from `Application` for init the `Component` and make an `@Inject` next:

```
class TheApplication: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val net: NetworkModule = Dagger...
    }
}
```

Theoretically when I put the `Dagger...` it should be `DaggerNetworkComponent` but I rebuild project and still missing.
Anyone can explain to me for what is the `Application.class` made for and how I can continue?

Comment: Please share your `component` code

Comment: I post one component code, I don't know if it's the same one you ask me

Comment: Why is your `@Component` called `NetworkModule` which cyclicly refers to itself as a module for some reason? While your actual network module is called `NetworksModule`?

Comment: The names are randomly choose nothing related with them

Comment: I recommend you start by reading some guides on Dagger2 first

Comment: @David, In `TheApplication` class have you initialise your component?

Comment: @Maddy I can't it doesn't appear my DaggerNetworkComponent after Rebuild Project

Comment: @Zun Did you know anyone related with my question? I search info but is so complex and extend, and in some guides didn't create an `Aplication.class` to init the `Component` and init it in the activity who inject the dependency.

Comment: Everything looks fine with your code. I assume that dagger annotation processor are  not connected or not configured. Check if dagger annotation processor is added as dependency through "kapt" configuration instead of "annotatinProcessor"

Comment: @Link182 thanks I solve the DaggerNetworkComponent problem, now I should understand how code works and how to work with Application class extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

> AppComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class]) 
@Singleton 
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: MyApp)
}
```

> NetworkModule.kt

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("YOUR_BASE_URL")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApi(retrofit: Retrofit): WebApi {
        return retrofit.create(WebApi::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(
        interceptors: ArrayList<Interceptor>
    ): OkHttpClient {
        val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
        interceptors.forEach {
            clientBuilder.addInterceptor(it)
        }
        return clientBuilder.build()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideInterceptors(): ArrayList<Interceptor> {
        val interceptors = arrayListOf<Interceptor>()
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            } else {
                HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
            }
        }
        interceptors.add(loggingInterceptor)
        return interceptors
    }
}
```

> MyApp.kt

```
class MyApp : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: MyApp
            private set
    }

    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
        private set


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        initComponent()
    }

    private fun initComponent() {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
    }
}
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
            android:name=".MyApp"
            ....
```

Comment: For what are the extra provides you made at the `NetworkModule.kt`? And how works `MyApp.kt` and for what is for? I didn't understand the functionality.

Comment: `MyApp` is `Application` class, I have created `AppComponent` with Application scope

Comment: @David other provider methods are for providing dependencies of interceptors and `OkHttpClient`. You can remove/modify it as per your use case.

Comment: If it's not a lot of work, can you explain me why should I use an `Aplication` class instead to initialize the `DaggerNetworkComponent` inside the class I want to inject? (How you can see I'm newest with Dagger2). And now how I should inject `Retrofit` ?

Comment: @David, sorry didn't get your question! But as per my understanding, I have just used the `Application` class to define `AppComponent` to the app level. As you defined `fun inject(app: MyApp)` in `AppComoment` it is required to inject component in the Application class.

Comment: thank for the info, one last question is how and where I should inject now de dependency? I have a .kt where I have a request to a Retrofit instance. Should be there? In case that if as it should be?

Comment: @David, say for example I want to use WebApi, then `@Inject
    lateinit var webApi: WebApi`

Comment: Can you explain a bit agter doing all these thing how can I apply the code, suppose I need a reference of web api, where and when should I write this?